# Check used space in Google Persistent Disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I have a lot of persistent disks attached to PODs running in GCE(Google Container Engine)

How can I check/monitor the used space of them without entering each of the POD?

Also is it possible to set up some alert when disk is almost full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always enable [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/) which will allow to [setup alerts and monitor the resources](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/12/monitoring-Container-Engine-with-Google-Cloud-Monitoring.html) used by the PODs.